# UpdateView unable to process POST request - form is not callable?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

According to the documenation on UpdateView this should be really simple and indeed the form is showing with the content from the database, but when clicking the submit button django displays a message saying:

```
'ProfileForm' object is not callable'.
```

Why would it need a callable form ? The form works well with CreateView for example so no problem there, dont get why it would complain now.

I have researched stackoverflow and search on google and indeed there are results, but none of them seem to apply to my situation as I dont see that im making any mistakes although clearly I apparently am according to django.

My code is as follows:

```
class PortfolioEditBase(UpdateView):
    post_req = False
    url_name = ''

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.post_req = True
        return super(PortfolioEditBase, self).get_form(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PortfolioEditBase, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post_req'] = self.post_req
        context['profile_id'] = self.kwargs['profile_id']
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(self.url_name, args=self.kwargs['profile_id'])


class PortfolioEditGeneralInfo(PortfolioEditBase):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileForm
    url_name = 'plan:general-info-edit'
    template_name = 'plan/portfolio/edit/general_info_edit.html'
```

Profile form has the following code:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['company', 'exchange', 'ticker',
              'investment_stage', 'investment_type']
    widgets = {
      'earnings_growth': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 1, 'rows': 2}),
    }
```

This is the relevant urls.py code:

```
url(r'^portfolio/general-info/edit/(?P<profile_id>[0-9]+)$', views.PortfolioEditGeneralInfo.as_view(), name='general-info-edit'),
```

I dont think the error message django gives me makes any sense. How about giving an error message that says a little more about what the actual problem is. Using function based views this is pretty simple and works with few lines of code, but class based views are suppose to be "best practice". It seems to try to fetch the form data, but i dont get why it would have any problems with that and why it would call a from instead of fetch the data with request.POST.

Do anyone know what is wrong here ? So annoying when its suppose to be so simple. The other class based views ived used has been working almost without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in `form_valid` method. It should be `form_vaild` instaed of `get_form`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.post_req = True
    return super(PortfolioEditBase, self).form_valid(form)
```

`get_form` method expecting form class as argument. But you are passing form instance.